# How to center a widget in a row in a PyQt grid layout

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I'm tryin to center a row with pyqtgrid and I cant figure it out I tried stretches and aligns but it doesn't seem to work not sure what I'm doing wrong. What im looking for is for the left aligned window "Class Subs" to be in the middle of the row that its in here is a MRE

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTextEdit,QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Subs(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        font = QFont("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(30)
        self.setFont(font)
        self.setText("Center Placeholder")
        self.setFixedWidth(500)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)


class SecondarySub(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parents):
        super().__init__()
        self.parents = parents
        self.setText("placeholder")
        font = QFont("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(30)
        self.setFont(font)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setFixedWidth(1000)
        self.setFixedHeight(100)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        grid_lay = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid_lay)
        self.widget_sub = Subs()

        self.widget_sub.setFixedWidth(800)
        self.widget_sub.setFixedHeight(50)
        print(self.widget_sub)

        # widgets
        grid_lay.addWidget(SecondarySub(self.widget_sub))
        grid_lay.addWidget(SecondarySub(self.widget_sub))
        grid_lay.addWidget(self.widget_sub)
        grid_lay.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(grid_lay)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: The documentation shows that [`addWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addWidget) also has an *alignment* keyword argument: `grid_lay.addWidget(self.widget_sub, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)`

Comment: @musicamante You should make this comment an answer.

Comment: @V.K I'm not on my computer, so I can't do a thorough research, but I'm pretty sure that there are at least 3/4 duplicates for this.

Comment: thanks @musicmante this fixed my issue. Just as a note for anyone reading you also need specify the row and column as well so in my case the third row would be number 2 since we count from zero and column would be number 0 so final code would be `grid_lay.addWidget(self.widget_sub, 2, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)` or to only align horizontally `grid_lay.addWidget(self.widget_sub, 2, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)`